# Powershell Script to create the file

Tags: powershell

I am new in Powershell. I tried to create the "dummy file" which is mentioned in the file.

For example, in the attached sheet, I have a file name called "Sheet" and there are total 5 files with different formats like - file1.pdf, file2.txt, file3.PNG, file4.docx, and file5.xlsx

I want to create the dummy file according to the file format.

So far I tried this code but it is not working. Please help me with it.

Thanks in advance

Screenshot:
[image]

So far I tried this code but not working -

```
$file_list = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\JamesAlam\Downloads\Sheet.txt"
$destination_folder = "C:\Users\JamesAlam\Downloads\Example"
$null = New-Item -Path $destination_folder -ItemType Directory -Force
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
     Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination $destination_folder -Recurse
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Copy-Item` you should use `New-Item`. ;-)

Comment: You need to be more clear about what qualifies a "dummy file". What's a dummy png file to you? What's a dummy docx file to you? Is a zero-bytes file just with the file extension acceptable? Or does it have to actually be a valid instance of that type of file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should usethe [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) cmdlet to create the new files. Also, you can simplify your script. If you add `-Force` to the `New-Item` cmdlet, it will also create the directory structure:

```
$destination_folder = "C:\Users\JamesAlam\Downloads\Example"

Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\JamesAlam\Downloads\Sheet.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Path (Join-Path $destination_folder $_) -Force
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate.. appreciate your enormous help... this code is working perfectly :D